# ListView is not displaying anything but is displayed when search view is clicked

Tags: android, android-viewpager, baseadapter, searchview

I have an activity named FriendListActivity which contains 3 tabs namely CHAT ,GROUP and CONTACTS.FriendListActivity contains a viewpager which is being populated through Fragments using FragmentStatePagerAdapter .Now each fragment contains a list view which is being populated using BaseAdapter .

Following is the code of SearchView in FriendListActivity :

```
  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            Log.e("Text", query);
            PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = (PagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
            for (int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

                Fragment viewPagerFragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, i);
                if (viewPagerFragment != null && viewPagerFragment.isAdded()) {

                    if (viewPagerFragment instanceof ChatFragment) {
                        ChatFragment chatFragment = (ChatFragment) viewPagerFragment;
                        if (chatFragment != null) {
                            chatFragment.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of ChatFragment
                        }
                    } else if (viewPagerFragment instanceof GroupsFragment) {
                        GroupsFragment groupsFragment = (GroupsFragment) viewPagerFragment;
                        if (groupsFragment != null) {
                            groupsFragment.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of GroupsFragment
                        }
                    } else if (viewPagerFragment instanceof ContactsFragment) {
                        ContactsFragment contactsFragment = (ContactsFragment) viewPagerFragment;
                        if (contactsFragment != null) {
                            contactsFragment.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of ContactsFragment
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Here u can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.
            return false;
        }
    };
```

**AdapterFriendList.java**

The following code is populating the list view of ChatFragment :

```
public class Adapter_FriendsList extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private Context context;
private List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;
List<Bean_Friends> mStringFilterList;
ValueFilter valueFilter;

public Adapter_FriendsList(Context context, List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listBeanFriends = listBeanFriends;
    mStringFilterList = listBeanFriends;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listBeanFriends.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listBeanFriends.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Log.e("GetView", "Called");
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_chat_list, null);

    //Getting Views
    ImageView img_friend = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgFriend);
    TextView txtNameFriend = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNameFriend);
    // ImageView imgMoreOption = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMoreoption);
    TextView txtFriendsID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFriendsID);

  /*  imgMoreOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // hide the title bar
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.more_option);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });*/

    //Setting values in the views
    //Data source of Adpater is List.At a specific position in the list ,we get Bean_Friends object
    Bean_Friends bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(position);
    //Getting values from Bean_Friends
    String name = bean_friends.getName();
    Log.e("FriendNAmeAD", name);
    String url = bean_friends.getUrl();
    Log.e("urlAD", url);
    String extension = bean_friends.getExtension();
    String friendID = bean_friends.getFriendsID();

    //Initializing ApiConfiguration
    apiConfiguration = new ApiConfiguration();
    String api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
    String absoluteURL = api + "/" + url + "." + extension;
    Log.e("AbsoluteURLAD", absoluteURL);

    Picasso.with(context).load(absoluteURL).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(img_friend); //Loading image into the circular Image view using Picasso
    txtNameFriend.setText(name);//Setting name
    txtFriendsID.setText(friendID);
    return view;
}

public static boolean exists(String URLName) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // note : you may also need
        //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}


private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String str = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
        Log.e("constraint", str);
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Bean_Friends> filterList = new ArrayList<Bean_Friends>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    Bean_Friends bean_friends = mStringFilterList.get(i);
                    filterList.add(bean_friends);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values = mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        listBeanFriends = (ArrayList<Bean_Friends>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

My problem is that when i click on CHAT tab,nothing is displayed but when i click on SearchView presented on the Activity containing the chat tab,the contents of list view are displayed .I want the contents of CHAT tab to be displayed when the user press of swipe the screen.Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: you only click on `SearchView ` or you click on `SearchView ` and enter some text

Comment: @PhanVănLinh : I only click on SearchView

Comment: @PhanVănLinh: Please review the code on https://gist.github.com/DeepakRattan/46c01f789c66f30f4d7601889286e4be